# Prevent chrome extension from making ajax calls

Tags: javascript, asp.net, ajax, google-chrome, google-chrome-extension

I have an asp.net website with client javascript making lots of ajax calls back to the server. Is there any way I can prevent a google chrome extension from calling my ajax endpoints or to detect when they are being made by the chrome extension code and not my own javascript code. So far I have tested using the referer, httponly cookies, but there is no difference between the 2 calls. Any ideas would be appreciated.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

**No**, there is not.

Chrome extensions have elevated permissions. They 'out-permit' your website JavaScript code and may manipulate and call it.

Even if you add something like an anti CSRF token, an extension could still read it and bypass that protection. They can run JavaScript code on your site and make modifications to your own code on the site on the fly without notifying your or your users.

The only thing you can do is **not trust the client** with anything critical, treat *all* requests you receive as hostile and require clients to authenticate before making requests to your server.

(I'm assuming you mean a chrome extension running on your site)

Comment: Thanks for the reply. Yes, an extension running on our site. I'm not trusting the client, but our support team would prefer to avoid supporting code that we didn't write. I was considering a csrf token both in httponly cookie and in a javascript closure (that is sent with each ajax call) so the extension couldn't access it (the var in the closure), but this will cause lots of grief in terms of re-factoring our js code to support this. And maybe there is still a way around it?

Comment: @user2444499 That won't help one bit. They have access to your JavaScript before it runs. All they need to do is go to your script tag and re-factor your code themselves. They can simply add a `window.secretClosureScoped = yourSecretCloseScoped` to _your_ code (parsing it as a string for example). They simply out permit you, have better hooks and more permissions.

Comment: You can play cat and mouse and figure out clever ways to not display the site to people who have the extension, maybe 'wear them out' - likely that wouldn't work. If the extension wants to display a picutre of a cat eating a cheeseburger instead of your site or stealing the users' username and password when they enter it - they very well can. That's how extensions work and why users _explicitly_ have to let them run.